# PlacePicker.IntentBuilder search is not localized

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am using `PlacePicker.IntentBuilder` to choose a nearby places from the map. Everything is working as expected, but top search bar suggestions is not localized e.g.
I am living in Saudi Arabia and when I write applebees, it suggest me all applebees in USA. How can I make this search localized.
Any help will be appreciated.

My code is:

```
    PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
    LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng(
           getLocation().getLatitude(), getLocation().getLongitude()), 
           new LatLng(getLocation().getLatitude(), getLocation().getLongitude()));

    builder.setLatLngBounds(bounds);        

    startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()),
           PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Below is the screen shot of my result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i remember you can give a region to encapsulate search area. Here is [reference](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/ui/PlacePicker.IntentBuilder).

You need to use `setLatLngBounds` method.

**UPDATE**

Also make sure to use [LatLngBound.Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder) for more elegant code and optmized region since you have points more than 2.

Good luck

Emre

Comment: setLatLngBounds only Sets the starting viewport for the map.

Comment: Just give it a try

Comment: This is my try so far.
PlacePicker.IntentBuilder builder = new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds(new LatLng( 15.199386, 43.096619), new LatLng( 34.452218, 42.745056) );
builder.setLatLngBounds(bounds);
startActivityForResult(builder.build(getActivity()), PLACE_AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);

Answer (score 0):

Adding Lat Lang Bounds will set the starting viewport of the map and simultaneously return places around that bounds:

```
 public class PlacePickerActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final int PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST = 1;
        private TextView mName;
        private TextView mAddress;
        private TextView mAttributions;
        private static final LatLngBounds BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(37.398160, -122.180831), new LatLng(37.430610, -121.972090));

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_picker);
            mName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mAddress = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            mAttributions = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            Button pickerButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickerButton);
            pickerButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try {
                        PlacePicker.IntentBuilder intentBuilder =
                                new PlacePicker.IntentBuilder();
                        intentBuilder.setLatLngBounds(BOUNDS_MOUNTAIN_VIEW);
                        Intent intent = intentBuilder.build(PlacePickerActivity.this);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, PLACE_PICKER_REQUEST);

                    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException
                            | GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```